# rCharts hPlot groups order

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I've created a stacked area plot with `hPlot` from `rCharts` package. Code:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1:5),3), value = rnorm(15, mean = 10)
                , group = rep(LETTERS[1:3],5))
x

library(rCharts)

a <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "value", group = 'group', 
           data = x[order(x$group, decreasing = T),], type = 'area')
a$plotOptions(area = list(stacking = "normal"))
a
```

Now I am trying to change the order of the groups to appear but in every case it is the same order (A, B, C).

For example, I would like to get the order (C, B, A), so that the area of C appear on top of the plot. But the objective is the possibility to create a personalized order like (A,C,B).

How could I achieve it? Appreciate any help

**possible solution**: I've found out that the order is alphabetical, so adding a prefix to a variables will put them in order I want, i.e. a_A, b_C, c_B.

Answer (score 1):

Add `a$yAxis(reversedStacks = FALSE)` to it. Please note that I used the same data to show that it works when comparing the two (as highlighted by the top point point - mouse hover).

**Without the `reversedStacks`**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rCharts)
set.seed(123)
x <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1:5),3), value = rnorm(15, mean = 10), group = rep(LETTERS[1:3],5))
x <- x[order(x$group, decreasing = T),]
a <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "value", group = 'group', data = x, type = 'area')
a$plotOptions(area = list(stacking = "normal"))
#a$yAxis(reversedStacks = FALSE)
a
```

[image]

**With the `reversedStacks`**

```
a <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "value", group = 'group', data = x, type = 'area')
a$plotOptions(area = list(stacking = "normal"))
a$yAxis(reversedStacks = FALSE)
a
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's for a quick answer, but it doesn't work for me... I've added the line but it does nothing. Running your code exactly I don't get the same output as you

Comment: The above should work as I checked with and without it, make sure you re-run the `a <- hPlot ...`

Comment: Unfortunatly i get the same output in both cases. Probably the problem is in some configuration. Do you use a RStudio Viewer to output the plot?